# Oracle SQL stored procedure output in actual column name and table data format#Multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

```
create or replace procedure sp_mx_sal_emp 
AS 
fname varchar2(20); 
lname varchar2(25); 
sal Number(8,2); 
country VARCHAR2(40);
region VARCHAR2(25);
    
BEGIN 
    select e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary, c.country_name, r.region_name into fname, lname, sal, country, region from employees e 
    inner join departments d on d.department_id=e.department_id 
    inner join locations l on l.location_id=d.location_id 
    inner join countries c on c.country_id=l.country_id 
    inner join regions r on r.region_id=c.region_id 
    inner join jobs j on j.job_id=e.job_id 
        where e.salary=(select max(e.salary) from employees e);
    
        dbms_output.put_line('fnames : '||fname);
        dbms_output.put_line('lnames : '||lname);
        dbms_output.put_line('max_sal : '||sal);
        dbms_output.put_line('country : '||country);
        dbms_output.put_line('region : '||region);
    
    
END;
```

exec sp_mx_sal_emp;

I am running thie stored procedure, as result is appearing as :-

```
fnames : Steven
lnames : King
max_sal : 24000
country : United States of America
region : Americas
```

I am expecting the result like this:
Actual column names and data in table format:-

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SALARY | COUNTRY_NAME | REGION_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Steven | King | 24000 | United States of America | Americas |

Please see the image for the output I am expecting: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncRt5.png)

Comment: If you want tabular output, using `dbms_output` seems like a poor choice.  You could use `dbms_output.put` rather than `put_line` to write multiple pieces of data on the same line.  Or you could make a single `dbms_output.put_line` call that wrote the data from each column.  But either way, you'd need to do additional formatting work to determine how to pad the data so that it aligned in a tabular format which is seldom a good investment of time.  Perhaps you want to return a `sys_refcursor` rather than calling `dbms_output` and then let the caller handle formatting.

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question. Also, please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

Comment: Don't use PL/SQL at all. Just write a normal select statement standalone outside of any `BEGIN END;` block. Learn what SQL can do and only employ PL/SQL when you need procedural programming that goes beyond the SQL language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the values on a single line then don't use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` multiple times.

Either:

1. Concatenate all the values together into a single string and use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` once; or
2. Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT` for the first values and then `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` for the final value.

Something like this:

```
create procedure sp_mx_sal_emp 
AS 
BEGIN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    RPAD('fnames', 20, ' ')
    || ' ' || RPAD('lnames', 25, ' ')
    || ' ' || RPAD('sal', 10, ' ')
    || ' ' || RPAD('country', 40, ' ')
    || ' ' || RPAD('region', 25, ' ')
  );
  FOR r IN (
    select e.first_name,
           e.last_name,
           e.salary,
           c.country_name,
           r.region_name
    from employees e 
         inner join departments d on d.department_id=e.department_id 
         inner join locations l on l.location_id=d.location_id 
         inner join countries c on c.country_id=l.country_id 
         inner join regions r on r.region_id=c.region_id 
         inner join jobs j on j.job_id=e.job_id
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      RPAD(r.first_name, 20, ' ')
      || ' ' || RPAD(r.last_name, 25, ' ')
      || ' ' || TO_CHAR(r.sal, '999990.00')
      || ' ' || RPAD(r.country, 40, ' ')
      || ' ' || RPAD(r.region, 25, ' ')
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```